# python & shell : how to capture value out side scope in shell script which has embedded python code

Tags: python-3.x, bash, shell

The below embedded py code, and get a value from shell , and again in python code scope value updated and to be used shell script scope..  I am not getting the output value of pvar variable, which is at last line

```
#!/bin/bash
export ans=100
cat << EOF > pyscript.py
#!/usr/bin/python3 -tt
import subprocess
print('............This is Python')
pvar=$ans
pvar=pvar+400
print(" Updated value of pvar =", pvar)
EOF

chmod 770 pyscript.py`enter code here`
$./pyscript.py
echo "The value of  pvar in bash = " $pvar
===========
```

Comment: =====Output of the above code is ===
............This is Python
 Updated value of pvar = 500
The value of  pvar in bash =
[root@srv101 Scripts]#
=======

Answer (score 0):

You need to use command substitution to get the results of the script into a bash variable:

```
pvar=$(./pyscript.py)
echo $pvar
# ............This is Python Updated value of pvar = 500
```